# expect ssh script runs but doesn't show all of the ouput

Tags: php, ssh, expect

i have an expect ssh script that been executed from html page running a php script.
the script runs ok but i dont see all its ouput on the ie screen.
any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 

set timeout -1
set max_match 10000

set var1 [lindex $argv 0]
set var2 [lindex $argv 1]
set var3 [lindex $argv 2]
set var4 [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host
expect "Password:"
send "XXXX\r"
expect -re "user@host>"
send "[join $argv]\r"
expect -re "]$"
send "exit"
interact
```

Comment: If you're invoking this from a web page, how are you going to interact? Change `interact` to `expect eof`

Comment: What exactly do you see and how exactly is that different from what you want to see?

Comment: I changed to expect eof and now its keep running endlessly. while running it from cli i see all the output from another script that run in another server. while running it from web page i only see the first line after the remotly script start to run and thats it.

Comment: Look like the session is closed before all data has been transmited back.

Answer (score 0):

Using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html)...

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('user@host');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'XXXX')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read("user@host>");
$ssh->write("[join $argv]\r");
echo $ssh->read("]$");
$ssh->write("exit");
?>
```

That's based on your code. If I were you I'd try replacing the \r with \n and I'd try adding a \n after exit as well.